# JS value отмеченных чекбоксов

Tags: javascript, html

Помогите, пожалуйста, добавить в `<label id="lbl">` value отмеченных чекбоксов.

```
<tr th:each="mess : ${messages}">
    <td name="id" th:text="${mess.id}"></td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxName" id="checkbox_check" th:value="${mess.id}" onclick="check()"/>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
     <form th:action="@{/removes}" method="post">
      <label id="lbl">
        <input type="submit" value="Удалить" style="display: block; margin-right: auto;" />
      </label>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

JS код ниже почему-то дублирует добавление строк с уже ранее выбранными чекбоксами.
Например,
выбираем ЧБ с value=10, добавляется строка

`<input type="hidden" id="remid" value="10"/>`

потом ещё выбираем ЧБ с value=20, добавляются уже 2 строки

`<input type="hidden" id="remid" value="10"/>`

`<input type="hidden" id="remid" value="20"/>`
и т.д.
Нужно добавлять по одной строке при выборе чекбокса.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
function check() {
  if (document.getElementsByName('checkbox_check')) {
    var checkValues = document.getElementsByName('checkbox_check').value;
    var divStr = '<input type="hidden" id="remid" value="' + checkedValue + '"/>';
    for (var checkValue of checkValues) {
        if (checkValue.checked) {
            document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML += divStr;
            }
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: не совсем понятен механизм, ты добавляешь checked, первый раз у тебя checked только один,  он и добавился, второй раз их уже два, ты их и добавляешь, в чем проблема? чтоб один добавился надо с предыдущего убрать checked

Comment: Задумка добавлять в form все отмеченные чекбоксы, что бы потом передать на бэк при нажатии удалить.

Comment: я не вижу полного функционала, но теоретически не хватает проверки на уже добавленные checkbox, чтоб не дублировались, или может перетирать ранее записанные данные?

Comment: document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML += divStr; 
перед этим действием в начале срабатывания функции может просто обнулить этот блок?

Comment: Была такая идея, по проверке на checked, но поскольку в JS не силен, то решил обратиться. Ладно, попробую своять проверку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вставьте обнуление перед передачей обновленного массива

```
document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = '';
```

```js
<script th:inline="javascript">
  function check() {
    if (document.getElementsByName('checkbox_check')) {
      var checkValues = document.getElementsByName('checkbox_check').value;
      var divStr = '<input type="hidden" id="remid" value="' + checkedValue +       '"/>';
      document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML = '';
      for (var checkValue of checkValues) {
          if (checkValue.checked) {
              document.getElementById("lbl").innerHTML += divStr;
              }
      }
  } 
}
</script>
```

Comment: Спасибо, подошло. Пришлось, правда, из `<label id="lbl">` всё остальное убирать, т.к. всё очищается.